# Expose private method when doing dependency injection

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection

I've got a template class 'Foo' and another non template class 'Bar'.
I want to have instance of Bar inside of Foo and expose one of Bar's functions that is private only to Foo.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
    bool Func()
    {
        return m_bar->DoSomething();
    }
}

class Bar
{
private:
    bool DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: You can read [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the `Foo` template a friend of `Bar`:

```
class Bar
{
    template <class T> friend class Foo;
    // same as before...
};
```

Now, any `Foo` instantiation is able to invoke private member functions of `Bar`. The code compiles, but you could still consider whether this is worth the drawbacks: as pointed to by @StoryTeller in the comments, a friend class not only is a very strong coupling, it guarantees access to *any* data member and member function that are probably `private` or `protected` for some reason. In other words, `friend` classes do violate encapsulation, and there should be a strong argument for using such a scheme.

Note, however, that you don't really inject `Bar`. Injection happens from the outside, e.g. by passing a `Bar` instance to the constructor of `Foo`, and/or by instantiating `Foo` with a `Bar` template parameter. In your case, this could be

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_bar;
    // same as before...
};

Foo<Bar> instance;
//  ^^^ inject dependency on Bar
```

Comment: *"Now, any Foo instantiation is able to invoke private member functions of Bar"* - And a whole lot more